# Text file not opening after i wrote to it using FileWriter from clob in mysql database(retreival using jdbc)

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{
        Connection myconn=null;
        Statement stat=null;
        PreparedStatement st=null;
        CallableStatement cal=null;
        ResultSet res=null;
        String dburl="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbms";
        String user="root";
        String password="admin";
            int charread;
        try {
            myconn=DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, user, password);

            System.out.println("connected to database successfully");
            File f=new File("test.txt");
            stat=myconn.createStatement();
            res=stat.executeQuery("select exp_clob from dbmslabprgm1test.new_table where ID=1");
            FileWriter writer=new FileWriter(f);
            System.out.println("Reading clob from db");
            /*while(res.next()) {
                System.out.println(res.getString(1));
            }*///This comment was written to check whether clob is retrieved correctly into console.It printed the whole clob correctly
            if(res.next()) {
                Reader reader=res.getCharacterStream("exp_clob");
                char[] buf=new char[1024];
                while((charread=reader.read(buf))!=1) {
                    writer.write(buf,0,charread);
                    System.out.println(".");
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
```

I ran this code on eclipse IDE.It ran for sometime(I think it entered some sort of infinite loop and consumed memory a lot)and later eclipse said that it had some internal error(said that memory consumption was critically high) and stopped responding.Later I opened test.txt in file explorer even this text file made notepad not to respond.by the way,similar code ran for blob retrieval correctly.I think there is no problem with resultset because the commented part runs perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
while(reader.read(buf)!=1)
```

reads from the buffer until the length read is exactly 1 - this is unlikely ever to happen so you get a endless loop.

You probably meant to test for `-1` which indicates the end of file.

Howerever just changing this is not enough as your next line is:

```
writer.write(buf);
```

This writes the **whole** of `buf` to the output - but the reader may not have filled the whole buffer.

You need to use something like:

```
for (;;) {
  int charsRead = reader.read(buf);
  if (charsRead < 0) {
    break;
  }

  writer.write(buff, 0, charsRead);
}
```

You must also call `close()` on the writer once you have finished writing.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but now the file is opening,but it is an empty file

Comment: You are also not calling `close` on the writer.

Comment: Wow....it worked perfectly...thanks a lot...and also where can I get exact picture of all the streams and there related classes and methods...can a blob store any kind of file...

Comment: sir,can u pls answer this,even after I followed whatever u said here,i couldn't get out put on the following link https://stackoverflow.com/q/46782558/6877706?sem=2     Empty file after writing into.txt using file writer